# RecyclerView calls onBindViewHolder() on all items if RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

View structure:

```
<CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </ConstraintLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

What actually happens is, that second `RecyclerView` in the list acts weird. Usueally `onBindViewHolder` method gets called on visibile items. Well, in my case, it calls on all items - thus, I've problems of setting `Listeners` on specific items (when they're binded). I must use `NestedScrollView`. Is there a solution for this nonsense?

Comment: can you post what your adapter looks like?

Comment: @trpride Added. I dont think it's `Adapter` fault though.

Comment: if you are used recycler view with wrap content in nested scroll view,Adapter will create all views for your adapter . if all are same vertical list you can use single recyler with viewtype

Comment: @RajasekaranM I set "match_parent" to my RecyclerView and it still binds all items.

Comment: use without nested scroll view because nested scroll view avoid all other vertical scrolls

Comment: @RajasekaranM Is there a possibility to have collapsing toolbar with two recyclerview and not have a `NestedScrollView` as parent?

Comment: I'm sorry no :-)

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to come up with a workaround. I set my mRecyclerViews `nestedScrollingEnabled` to `false` and then set a listener for my `mNestedScrollView`.

Listner:

```
mNestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrollChanged()
           {
                    View v = (View)mNestedScrollView.getChildAt(mNestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);

                    int diff = (v.getBottom() - (mNestedScrollView.getHeight() + mNestedScrollView.getScrollY()));

                    if (diff == 0) {
                       // pagination
                    }
           }
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue :/. Recyclerview will still call all the views.